# Advanced jQuery filtering jQuery array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, jquery-selectors, filter

Question please:

```
var ids = ['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3', 'user_666'];
```

My HTML

```
<div id="chatUsers">
   <div id="user_1">username-1</div>
   <div id="user_2">username-2</div>
   <div id="user_5">username-5</div>
</div>
```

How to using jQuery make my container looks like this:

```
<div id="chatUsers">
   <div id="user_1">username-1</div>
   <div id="user_2">username-2</div>
   <div id="user_3">username-3</div>
   <div id="user_666">username-666</div>
</div>
```

Remove div with `id="user_5"` (we have no this in our ids list) and add div with id="user_666" (in our ids list).

Thank you very much!

I'm tried something like that, but this not work:

```
jQuery('#chatUsers').filter(function() {
   var a = jQuery(this).find('div');
   alert ("Filtering: divs count: " + a.length);
   //if (!a.length)
   //return true;
   var id =  a.attr('id');  
   if (jQuery.inArray(id,  ids) >= 0)
      return false;
   return true;
}).remove();
```

Comment: Are you trying to build the markup from your array or are you trying to modify existing markup with your array?

Comment: I'm trying to modify existing markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work, and avoid disrupting existing items:

```
var ids = ['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3', 'user_666'];   

$('#chatUsers').children().filter(function() {
     return ids.indexOf(this.id) === -1;
}).remove();

var length = ids.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (!document.getElementById(ids[i])) {
        $('<div>', { id: ids[i], text: ids[i] }).appendTo('#chatUsers');    
    }
}
```

It doesn't set the text exactly right when appending new ones. I'm assuming in your real code, you've got an object property in the array that you can use for that.

It also doesn't order them when appending, but that would be possible with `insertAfter()`.

Answer (score 1):

If the array holds all of the elements you want to be in the list then you can start with an empty element and add all of the elements from the list, something like:

```
   $("#chatUsers").children().remove();

   var ids = ['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3', 'user_666'];   

   for ( id in ids ) {
     $("#chatUsers").append( '<div id="' + id + '">username-X</div>' );   
   }
```

This would be much simpler than trying to work out what you already have in the element and then amending that.

Comment: Thanks. It's simpler, but I need other solution.

Comment: why? this solution gives the same end result with less shenanigans.

Comment: If you want an immediate change, build the html in a string instead of appending in your loop. Then set the html for the container.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aTkPZ/2/

And here is the JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    var ids = ['user_1', 'user_2', 'user_3', 'user_666'];   
    var div = $('#chatUsers');
    var selector = '#' + ids.join(', #');
    div.find('div').not(selector).remove(); // remove ones not in the list
    for (var i = 0, max = ids.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (!div.find('#' + ids[i]).length)
            div.append('<div id="' + ids[i] + '">username-' + ids[i].replace('user_','') + '</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh man, I'm competing against @Dave Ward. I admit defeat now. ;-) Though I actually think our solutions are fairly similar. His is probably slightly faster, though.